# Hellinger Distance in Scala

Tags: scala, math, machine-learning

Given 2 `Array[Double]` which contains discrete probability distributions, how do I implement the [Hellinger Distance](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22725/what-is-hellinger-distance-and-when-to-use-it) in Scala?

```
def hellingerSimilarity(a1: Array[Double], a2: Array[Double]): Double = {


}
```

I am trying to use `scala.math.sqrt` function but it only works for a single `Double` and not an `Array`. I am used to Python's [pairwise metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics.pairwise) , is there a similar library in Scala/Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is just the mathematical formula in scala code:

```
def hellingerSimilarity(a1: Array[Double], a2: Array[Double]): Double = {
  val tupleSum = a1.zip(a2).map(x => pow(sqrt(x._1) - sqrt(x._2),2)).reduce(_+_)
  (1/sqrt(2)) * sqrt(tupleSum)
}
```